# How to generate server.log in custom folder location in wildfly-8.2.0.Final

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, wildfly-8

I am facing a problem regarding ***server.log*** file generation in **Wildfly-8.2.0.Final** AS.

Below is the `size-rotating-file-handler` definition used in logging subsystem `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">` of **standalone-full-ha.xml**.

```
<size-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="false">
      <level name="DEBUG"/>
      <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
      <rotate-size value="500k"/>
      <max-backup-index value="5"/>
      <append value="true"/>
</size-rotating-file-handler>
```

The above works fine and it generates ***server.log*** in **${WILDFLY_HOME}/standalone/log** folder. I would like to have a custom location for ***server.log*** and hence, modified the **path** attribute to contain the complete custom path and removed **relative-to** attribute as shown below.

```
<file path="D:/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone/log/server.log"/>
```

But, with the above changes, ***server.log*** is getting generated in custom location but facing the below problems:

- log statements are getting generated without date in it. for e.g.:

  12:16:11,800 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" starting
- Complete logs are not observed in the log file and for example, "server is started..." will be the last line and a quarter of the log statements are not printed.

Please help me.

Edited on 10/May/2016: added the below configuration.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">
        <add-logging-api-dependencies value="false"/>
        <use-deployment-logging-config value="true"/>
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <size-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="false">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <file path="${custom.path}/server.log"/>
            <rotate-size value="500k"/>
            <max-backup-index value="5"/>
            <append value="false"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </size-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
```

Comment: In which file **<file path="D:/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone/log/server.log"/>** is located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you did not specified a pattern (and probably this is why the date/time are not in the log).

```
<size-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="false">
  <level name="DEBUG"/>
  <file path="D:/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone/log/server.log"/>
  <rotate-size value="500k"/>
  <max-backup-index value="5"/>
  <append value="true"/>
  <formatter>
   <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
  </formatter>
</size-rotating-file-handler>
```

Pattern example with date/time:

```
<formatter name="PATTERN">
  <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
</formatter>
```

Can you provide full log configuration? Maybe the  "server is started..." is not showing because you didnt put the file handler in right category.

Comment: Many thanks for the response ..  fhofmann. I added / modified formatter to PATTERN to CONSOLE and SIZE ROTATING FILE handlers and could get the date properly but still "server is started..." is not showing. I had copied the logging subsystem in the blog.

Comment: The category and the handleres looks right. Maybe the message is logged before loggin subsystem is started. Take a look in /standalone/configuration/logging.properties and configure it to use your file. More info [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Logging+Configuration) in the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I did it for wildfly 26, configuration is same in most of case. You can follow below 2 steps to change the configuration.

Step 1 --> Go to /standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
Go to line 84 and and replace the line with "/filename.log"/>

[image: refer the screenshot and don't forget to put filename.log]

Step 2 --> Create the folder in the given path.. It is done.[image: Done]